# justify-content is not working well,cant make nav in the end of header

Tags: html, css

```
nav{
    
    height: 50px;
    color:#9b9b9bff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
    border:1px solid green;

    

}
```

this is css file
and

```
<header>
    <img src="logo2.png"  class="logo2"><img>
    <img src="logo.png"  class="logo"><img>
    <nav>
         
    xcxzcccxzcxz

    </nav>






</header>
```

this is html

I want to put  nav  in end of header
the html hase 2 logos and I want that you never menssion it ,its for e.g and i can see it
but I want mostly help on nav

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pnL0tbgx/

Answer (score 1):

I tried in my js snippet here, it worked i guess, i just slightly changed the code

```css
header{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between
}

nav{
    
    height: 50px;
    color:#9b9b9bff;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px

}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="img-section">
     <img src="logo2.png"  class="logo2"><img>
     <img src="logo.png"  class="logo"><img>
    </div>
    <nav>Logo Text</nav>
</header>
```